# MySQL row number with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now I have this:

```
SELECT
@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum,
T1.*
FROM
(
    SELECT user.username, points
    FROM scores
    JOIN users AS user ON user.id = scores.user_id
) AS T1, (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS r
ORDER BY T1.points DESC, rownum ASC
```

And this returns usernames, points and row number. Points are ordered but row numbers are all messed up. If I put ORDER BY into the nested select then row nubmers are ordered but points are not. So what I need to change so that I get points ordered in descending order and row number would be in ascending, what I wanna create is leaderboards, so that user whit most point is first etc.

[image: mysql return]

Comment: which dbms system are you using?

Comment: if you are using MS Sql Server you can use Row_Number https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin with MySQL

Comment: @Miko . . . Edit your question and show how the ordering is not working.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Now you can see where the problem is

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need your `rownum` to be paired up with `points` that have been pre-ordered. Hence you need to move `ORDER BY` on `points` into the nested select:

```
SELECT
@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum,
T1.*
FROM
(
    SELECT user.username, points
    FROM scores
    JOIN users AS user ON user.id = scores.user_id
    ORDER BY points DESC
) AS T1, (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS r
ORDER BY rownum ASC
```

Comment: Row numbers are ordered correctly but points are still spread all around

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT (@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS rownum,
       us.*
FROM (SELECT u.username, s.points
      FROM scores s JOIN
           users u
           ON u.id = s.user_id
      ORDER BY s.points DESC
     ) us CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rownum := 0) params;
```

Basically, this just leaves the ordering in the subquery.

If `points` is not a number, then use `ORDER BY (s.points + 0) DESC` in the subquery.  Or fix the data so it is stored as a number.

Comment: I changed "us CROSS JOIN" to "as T1 CROSS JOIN" because otherwise it gives me error that T1 table doesn't exists. But despite the change result is the same, number rows are ordered but points are not

Comment: It's integer, I checked that :)